# Windows 10 Upgrade causes Oracle VM error - VT-x is not available

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

My ThinkPad went through a Windows 10 upgrade and since then my Oracle Virtual Machines are completely down. I get "VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)." error. OVM Version 5.2.30

```
 Things that I tried -> 

    1: Disable Hyper-V
          Turned it off from Windows features 

    2: BIOS settings for Virtualization
          BIOS -> Security -> 
        Intel Virtualization Technology - Enabled 
        VT-d Feature - Enabled

    3: Core Isolation -> Memory Integrity 
        I tried to turn this off from Windows Defender Settings. 
Once I turned it off, I was told the change requires system restart. 
After restart, the option was ON again. 
So I followed the Registry option but the 'Enabled' key was already at 0.
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity
```

While checking for solutions online I also realized my VM shows only 32 bit options for any system and not 64 bit. The solutions suggested online to fix that are similar the the ones I have mentioned above and none of the them worked for me. Has anyone else faced this problem and are there any other solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has a feature of windows sandbox. Which interrupts the working of virtualbox.

To resolve this:-

1. Go To `Control Panel`-->`Programs     and Features`
2. Choose `Turn Windows Features On or Off` on the left pane.
3. Uncheck `Windows Sandbox` (or something similar I don't remember clearly).
4. Restart

Comment: I don't have any option called 'sandbox' under the features to trun off-on

Comment: Download this tool from Microsoft https://bit.ly/2IfMtSm then, run the following command in powershell (must be admin) : `.\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.5.ps1 -Disable -AutoReboot `. It will turn off the credential guard. And may help if any security features (Core Isolation, App. Guard etc.) are enabled which require Hyper-V features.

Comment: @HarshitBhardwaj - thanks for this - this worked for me!